# unity mobile controls positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my code, my object the script is attached to always moves right, implying the second if is always met, no matter where on the screen I touch. The gameobject starts in the middle of the screen. It should move left if I touch to the left of the object. Am I missing something?

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (0);


        if (touch.position.x < transform.position.x)   {
            transform.Translate (-0.05f * speed, 0, 0); 
        } else if (touch.position.x > transform.position.x) {
            transform.Translate (0.05f * speed, 0, 0);
        }


    }
```

Comment: iirc, the position you're getting from `Input.GetTouch(0).position` is the position relative to the screen space, object positions are relative to the world space, you might want to convert them using something like `ScreenToWorldPoint()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to do what you want:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

    var point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y,
        transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z));

    Debug.DrawLine(Camera.main.transform.position, point, Color.green, 1);


    var delta = transform.position.x - point.x;

    if(Mathf.Abs(delta) < threshold)
    {
        return;
    }


    if (point.x < transform.position.x)
    {
        transform.Translate(-0.05f * speed, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (point.x >= transform.position.x)
    {
        transform.Translate(0.05f * speed, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

`Input.GetTouch()` will give you a `vector2`, It `x` and `y` are positions of your touch in the 2D screen of your phone/tablet. So you should convert the screen touch position to the world position(`x`,`y`, and `z` in 3D space) and then compare that world position with your object position.

The reason that you need to use **main camera** is that your touch should be converted to a 3d space and converting a 2D point to a 3D point needs a `Z` parameter. you will get this parameter from finding the difference of positions of **main camera** and object. You can get main Camera using `Camera.main`.

I have also added a `Debug.DrawLine()` to show you the exact point. Use [UnityRemote](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html) to test and see the line in **Editor**.

There is a `threshold` property to prevent flicking of game object.

**Note:** Keep in mind that this is just an example and it won't work for other camera angles.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! It would be great if you could explain where you derived point from? And also, when I am moving my gameobject horizontal across, if I hold my finger down on the screen, the gameobject will flick between both sides of the finger. I expected this, but can not think of an immediate solution.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without losing the smooth feel?

Comment: sure, search Dotween, It is a tween engine to do these kinds of tasks